# Wifi router flushing too often. IP collision or what?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, reset

I've needed like 6 months or so to track this issue with my Wifi router. Here are all the devices connected to my adsl router:

LAN
PC connected via LAN cable

WIFI
4 mobile devices
1 tablet
1 laptop
?? number of other mobiles (when friends come for a coffee)

The error manifests like this: I simply see router flushing connection just like I flushed it via the console - all lights (except power light) go off and then back on. To emphasize, it's not like a real restart when I turn the router off and on, it mostly resembles the `flush` command which you issue when you need a new IP.

I've noticed that it happens in these situations:
- I use laptop to browse the net, then send laptop to suspend mode, I then use a mobile to browse the net, then I awake the laptop and *then the router flushes the connection*
- I use mobile to browse the net, my mobile's screen goes off (thus deactivating wifi connection), my wife wants to use the net and - *puf - the router flushes*.

It **seems** that some device (laptop or mobile) saves the current IP into the cache and after being awaken, it wants to connect to router using the same IP. If in that moment some other device already got the same IP, the collision happens and the router flushes the connection so that each device gets its own IP.

Can this be the reason for flushing? If yes, how can I prevent it?

The router I have is Billion router given to me by my ISP.

Comment: Sounds like a failing router.  Did you ask your ISP for a replacement?

Comment: @techie007 Really? I've never though of it, but if your sure that collision cannot happen, then I'll ask for a replacement. Are you absolutely sure of what you're saying?

Comment: If you are renting the equipment from them, then they will help you diagnose and, if need be, replace it.  Am I 100% sure it's broken? No, that's impossible for me to tell.  But spending 5-10 minutes on the phone and getting a replacement to ensure it's not the problem sounds easier than 6 months of trying to diagnose some oddity in equipment that's not yours. :) "Collisions" really don't happen in routers (that's a Hub thing), and from what you're describing it sounds like your router is performing a partial reset for some reason, which isn't normal.

Comment: In general, if you hooked up 100 machines to a router, all with the same IP address, it shouldn't reset, or crash, or flush. :)